# ¿Por qué se dice "a menos que estudies", pero "si no estudias"?

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales, condicional

Cuando estás hablando sobre algo que podría ocurrir condicionalmente, se puede usar el subjuntivo:

> A menos que estudies, no aprobarás.

Pero igual se puede usar el indicativo con "si no":

> Si no estudias, no vas a aprobar.

Aunque puedes usar los dos, "si no estudies" o "a menos que estudias" suena muy raro. ¿Por qué se puede expresar el mismo pensamiento en dos maneras tan diferentes?

Comment: The first option is expressing an opinion, something hypothetical. In the second option you’re affirming a belief. ‘Unless you study, you won’t pass’. ‘If you don’t study, you will not pass’. https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31315/why-is-the-subjunctive-used-here

Comment: @Curtis, _Pero_ is not always the best word to translate _but_. You could use _Sino_ (even if pero and sino used to be synonyms) or _Mas_ (without accent).

Answer (score 3):

En el libro ["Gramática española: simple, compacto y claro" de Heike Pahlow, Silvia Martín Jiménez, Itziar Andraca Riffard, Blanca Lou Cotolí](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=LPG4BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola:%20simple,%20compacto%20y%20claro%20conjunciones%20subordinantes&source=bl&ots=sVhfL7T6kN&sig=ACfU3U33MX6b7bOXRwAwnExxW7V-cSt_4A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgraiytNrkAhXIIrkGHdZYDTQQ6AEwDHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola%3A%20simple%2C%20compacto%20y%20claro%20conjunciones%20subordinantes&f=false) encontramos un listado de conjunciones condicionales, de acuerdo con el cual **sólo se usa indicativo con "si" y "si no" y subjuntivo con el resto de las conjunciones**:

[image: Título]

[image: Listado]

Las formas "si no estudies" o "a menos que estudias" no son gramaticales.

El motivo por el cual "si no estudias" usa indicativo y "a menos que estudies" usa subjuntivo podría ser que la primera **contiene una afirmación**, mientras que la segunda es **pura condición**:

- Si no estudias (no estudias, y en caso de persistir en esa actitud), no vas a aprobar el examen.
- A menos que estudies, no vas a aprobar el examen (sólo aprobarás en la eventualidad de que estudies).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the few occasions when looking at the version in another language may help.

You would say

> if you do not study, you will not

expressing something almost timeless which applies in the past, now, and in the future.

If you say

> unless you study, you will not

you are talking about something hypothetical. After all s/he might study and then none of it will come to pass, indeed that is the whole point of the advice.

Comment: Both of them offer the opportunity for the individual to change the outcome by studying though, surely - neither is saying "as you haven't studied, you will not" which I can see would be a different thing.

Comment: @Curtis Parfitt-Ford It’s about conveying the speaker’s view - by using the indicative the speaker is asserting a belief. Using the subjunctive conveys a hypothesis and therefore lack of that certainty. The speaker chooses which to use depending on what they want to communicate.